# How to make a div to fit horizontal to rest of page?

Tags: html, css, image

hello i have problem with div i try everything, but i cant...
i want to cover all site (100vh and 100% width) with white color, without centered image, and animation background, you will understand when you see the site:
http://nevisu.co.uk/neviftp/

this is my problem:
http://nevisu.co.uk/neviftp/help.jpg

html

```
    <div id="top_white"></div>

    <div id="mid_white">
        <div id="left_white"></div>     
        <div id="transparent_logo"><img src="images/symbol_transparent.png"></div>
        <div id="right_white"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="bot_white"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div id="clr"></div>
<div id="black_container"></div>
```

css

```
body {
margin:0px auto;
font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
background:#000;
width:100%;
height:100%;
}

img {
max-width: 100%;
max-height: 100%;
}

#top_white {
display: block;
float:left;
width:100%;
height:10vh;
background:#FFF;
z-index:99;
}

#mid_white {
display: inline-block;
float:left;
width:100%;
max-height:60vh;
z-index:99;
}

#left_white {
display: inline-block;
float:left;
height:60vh;
width:33vw;
max-height: 640px;
background:#FFF;
}

#transparent_logo {
display: inline-block;
float:left;
/*background:url('../images/symbol_transparent.png') center center no-repeat;*/
height:60vh;
}

#right_white {
margin:0px auto;
position:absolute;
display: inline-block;
float:left;
width:300px;
height:60vh;
right:0px;
max-height: 640px;
background:#fff;
}

#bot_white {
position: absolute;
float:left;
width:100%;
height:30vh;
bottom: 0px;
background:#FFF;
z-index:99;
}

#clr {
clear: both;
}


#white_container  {
float:left;width:100%;height:100vh;position: absolute;
}

#black_container  {
float:left;background:#000; width:100%;height:4000px;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do is wrap your image.

http://jsfiddle.net/0oxqzbfe/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="imgWrapper">
        <img src="https://placekitten.com/g/200/200"/>
    </div>
</div>


.wrapper {
width:100%;
}
img {
width:100%;
}
.imgWrapper {
width:50%;
}
```

as see in the example the image will always be 50% of the body. even the image source file is 200px x 200px

you should use this structure.

```
<body 100%width>
    <div>white background width:20%</div>
    <div>center logo wrapper 
         width:60%;
         overflow:hidden;
            <img>transparent
            <img>rotating
    </div>
        white background width:20%
    <div>
</body>
```

Comment: yeah you have right :) i try this tommorow, thank you